# Trouble with splitting a constexpr function definition

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm having some trouble with breaking up a `constexpr` between a header and .ipp file. I've taken an example from [here](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/blob/master/wed/schurr_cpp11_tools_for_class_authors.pdf?raw=true) (looking at slide 29, the `str_const` class) but have tried to split it between an .hpp and an .ipp file for a cleaner header.

Header:

```
#pragma once

namespace Example
{
    class ErrCode
    {
    public:

    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr ErrCode (const int aCode, const char (& aMsg) [N]); //ctor

    constexpr ErrCode (const ErrCode & aErrCode) = default; //copy

    ErrCode & operator= (const ErrCode & aErrCode) = default; //operator=

    constexpr char operator[] (std::size_t aSize);

    //... a few other methods, all constexpr except return the string

    const int id;

    private:

    const char * const   mStrPtr;
    const std::size_t    mSize;

    }
}
#include "ErrCode.ipp"
```

ipp:

```
namespace Example
{
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr ErrCode::ErrCode (const int aCode, const char (& aMsg) [N] :
        id (aCode),
        mStrPtr (aMsg),
        mSize (N - 1)
    {
    }

    constexpr char ErrCode::operator[] (std::size_t aSize)
    {
        if (aSize < mSize)
        {
            return mStrPtr [aSize];
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::out_of_range ("");
        }
     }
}
```

The issue I'm having is with the compiler not making a connection between the signatures in the .hpp and the .ipp. For some reason, when I compile on VS 2017 (using v140 or 2015 toolset) I get an error about an overloaded member function not found in the class.

```
error C2511: 'char Example::ErrCode::operator [](std::size_t)': overloaded member function not found in Example::ErrCode"
```

where the error points to the line in the .ipp where the definition occurs.

Am I not allowed to break up these constexpr methods into a separate file? The compiler has no issue with these methods if I declare and define everything in the header alone.

Any help would be appreciated. If you cannot reproduce the error let me know.

Comment: I believe constexpr is implicitly inline, so you can't split it.

Comment: Try `constexpr char ErrCode::operator[] (std::size_t aSize) const`?  Second, please ensure the code you post (with *no other cose*) generates that error you post.